# Running an external jar file by pressing a JButton

Tags: java, swing, jar, jbutton, launch

I am trying to run a jar file that is in a separate directory from pressing a JButton.

I have the button and GUI setup but I cant figure out how to launch the separate jar file.

What do I put in this code block

```
private void jButton1MouseReleased(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                       

}
```

Comment: Do you want to load and execute code from the jar in the same JVM, or start it as a completely new process?

Comment: What have you researched till now?

Comment: in the same jvm, won't there be one jvm, and it will be executed as a new process in that jvm? doubt he wanted multiple jvm instances

Comment: I Want to start the other jar file as a separate process and close my current one

Answer (score 4):

Try This

```
try {
    Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File("F:\\Folder\\Folder\\folder\\yourprogram.jar"));
} catch (IOException ex) {
    System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
}
```

for example open a .exe file   ( Open ODBC DSN via java )

```
    try {
        Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File("C:\\Windows\\SysWOW64\\odbcad32.exe"));
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        try{
            Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File("C:\\Windows\\System32\\odbcad32.exe"));
        }catch(Exception exx)
        {
            System.out.println(exx.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Better to check if the machine has a Java installed (via System environment variables maybe?). Also, consider to use `/` instead of \\ as `/` is OS-independent. +1 for you :)