# Open a file in default application from Java GUI without using JFileChooser

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, file-io, jfilechooser

I have a JList holding objects of type

```
Result(String title, String content, String filePath)
```

This JList has a MouseListener. I would like to implement a double clicked MouseEvent that passess the selected result's filePath, so it can open the File outside of my Java GUI application.

For Example:

If I double click a Result object in the JList with
title: "Document1"
content: "This is Document1" 
filePath: "C:\doc1.doc"

I would like the program to open this document outside of the application in Microsoft Word.

In otherwords, how can I bypass JFileChooser and open a File outside of my application in its default application?

Comment: Over 3,000 views and no up votes :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you'r looking for `evt.getClickCount()`
Inside your *mouseEvent* method you can create a control statement like this:

```
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent ev){
 if(ev.getClickCount() ==2){
  try{
  java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File("path/to/file"));
}catch(FileNotFoundException ex){
//.....
}
}
}
```

Also check this  [link .](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14988741/running-an-external-jar-file-by-pressing-a-jbutton/14988840#14988840)

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I especially appreciated how you put it in the context of the mouseClicked method.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File("filePath"));
```

i.e.

```
Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File("C:/doc1.doc"));
```

It should open the file with the default application

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response. The only thing is the open method requires a File parameter and not a String.